# jquery onclick not working on element from .load() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-load

I have a PHP snippet in a separate file which I am loading in a javascript file using jquery:

```
let signUpMode = $(".modal");
  signUpMode.load("login_signup_popup.php");
```

This works because I am able to show this on screen. However, this snippet contains a button which I would like to click in the same javascript file where I loaded the snippet. something simple like:

```
$(".signupbtn").on("click", function(){
    console.log("signed Up");
  });
```

This click is, however, not working. `signupbtn` is a div element in the snippet. Somehow I am missing an extra step since jquery seems to not be recognizing the elements in the snippet.

Comment: 1] check whether you are able to  load the signupbtn div element in browser
2] specify js code after loading your php file, may be your dom is taking time to load

Comment: Try like this-> `$(document).on('click','.signupbtn',function(){ console.log("signed Up");});`

Comment: `signUpMode.load(...).on("click", ...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lazy loaded elements are not recognized from eventhandlers which are already initialized. So you have to set the event on a parent. This should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.signupbtn', function(){ 
    console.log("signed Up");
});
```

Comment: yep, that worked. (new to jquery)

Answer (score 2):

https://api.jquery.com/load/

You could use the complete function to check if it has loaded, or you could just put the button function inside there.

```
  let signUpMode = $(".modal");
  signUpMode.load("login_signup_popup.php", function() {
    $(".signupbtn").on("click", function() {
      console.log("signed Up");
    });
  });
```